# css border problem

Tags: css, border

For some reason I have a very ugly orange part of a border around a image.

Can anyone see why this is?

This is the HTML

```
<div class="preview">

            <a href="images/foto/full/280899624_6_5_j6.jpeg" title="Sportschool Raymond Snel" rel="lightbox"><img src="images/foto/full/280899624_6_5_j6.jpeg" alt="text" /></a>

</div>
```

This is the css

```
.preview {
    width: 85px; 
    height: 85px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 3px solid #2e2a26;
    }
```

The color code = FF6a00 but appears only one time in the css file.

```
a {
    color: #ff6a00;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 0px;
}
```

As you can see I already gave it a 0px, but for some reason the border is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.preview a:link img, .preview a:active img, .preview a:hover img, .preview a:selected img, .preview a:visited img{border-style:none;}
```

Comment: You forgot `a:visited`. But ... why not just `.preview a img` ?

Comment: That was my original thought, but the other night I had an issue where I did something similar, using a img to take off the border, but once I selected it the border came back. It was pretty strange, but I figured I'd offer this as an alternative in case Chris has the same problem.  Also, I added in visited.  Thanks for the catch!

Comment: great, it's a good way to do this. In my case I forget to post a part of css which was a container  for all the links with border properties. For the future your sollutions is great!

Answer (score 3):

Try `img { border: 0; }`

Comment: This is the best option IMO, because now borders will only appear when you explicitly specify them.

Comment: Indeed. That's why it's one of the first things I write when I start a new stylesheet.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following CSS it will make sure any image inside a link doesn't get a border.

```
a img { border:0px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to remove the border on images instead of just on the anchor. The border is actually coming from images inside anchors so the following will fix it:

```
img{border:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.preview a img { border: 0px; }
```

Comment: Probably the best option in the mix as it only relates to links inside your .preview div

Answer (score 1):

The border is because the image is a link (think about how links are blue by default - the same applies to image links, they have a border by default).

This line will fix it

```
.preview a img {border: 0;}
```

Comment: any particular reason for the -1 from whoever it was? To make your answer appear higher in the list?! If you're going to -1 at least leave a reason why you did it :/

Answer (score 0):

Just try and put border="0" inside img tag. Let me know if that helps.